# Parse.com - PHP Login - Missing Username

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

Hi I am using Parse and I try to logged in with PHP Code but everytime it writes me `{"code":200,"error":"missing username"}`

Here is the PHP Code:

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",  
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey
);          

$username = urlencode('username=test@abv.bg');
$password = urlencode('password=test');
$url = "https://api.parse.com/1/login/$username&$password";

$rest = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"GET");  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($rest);  
echo $response;   
curl_close($rest);
```

What I am missing ?

Comment: I think a `?` has to be before `$username`.

Comment: Yes this is the answer but you have to add ? in $url not in $username :) Thank you bro :)

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov The comment correctly says _before_ `$username`, not _in_ the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

? before $username in $url :)

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",  
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey
);          

$username = urlencode('username=test@abv.bg');
$password = urlencode('password=test');
$url = "https://api.parse.com/1/login/?$username&$password";

$rest = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"GET");  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($rest);  
echo $response;   
curl_close($rest);
```